# Template Rendering in EmberJs

Tags: jquery, templates, events, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'd like to know the event or others when any template is rendered.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="dashboard">
    <span>username</span><input type="text" id="username" />
    <span>email addr</span><input type="text" id="email" />
</script>

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('index', { path: '/' }, function() {});
    this.resource('dashboard', {path: '/dashboard'}, function() {});
});

App.DashboardController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({})

App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('dashboard', {   // the template to render
      controller: 'dashboard'        // the controller to use for the template
    }); 
  }
});
```

sample.js

```
function clearObj(){
  $("#username").val("");
  $("#email").val("");
}
```

I am going to run clearObj() function when the dashboard template is rendered.
Which event or function do I have to use?

I can go to the dashboard template by typing on addressbar /#/dashboard or clicking some button etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wight might help is the [`afterRender`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.6/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1785) hook of a view. When this hook runs you can be sure that everything has been rendered into the DOM.

For example subscribe to the hook in the `didInsertElement` and schedule the call to `afterRender`:

```
App.DashboardView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'processChildElements');
  },

  processChildElements: function() {
    $("#username").val("");
    $("#email").val("");
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.